# I can't read silverlight tag in IE !

Tags: silverlight

This is really weird.

Here's a simple markup

```
<div id="div1">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="640px" height="480px">
    </object>
</div>
```

and executing alert(document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML); shows me

```
<OBJECT type=application/x-silverlight-2 height=480 width=640 data=data:application/x-oleobject;base64,QfXq3+HzJEysrJnDBxUISgAIAAAlQgAAnDEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA></OBJECT>
```

Firefox or google chrome shows me correct markup. Only IE(tested on IE7) shows me above strange markup.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, but it should be expected that the Silverlight Object is rendered differently in varying browser.  This is done by the Silverlight.JS file.

Comment: Why not give the object tag an Id?

Comment: I'm writing a yui rich text editor plug-in that inserts silverlight content. Editor uses iframe inside and copy the iframe's content to textarea before the submit. And IE screws markup like the above.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the javascript?  Or are you just asking why it's different?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox return the html supplied by the original document in this case.

IE never does that, once it has parsed HTML and create the DOM it discards the original document text.  When you ask for innerHTML it constructs a new HTML string by analysing the DOM nodes and attributes held within the element.

At times this means you will see the result of mutations made by the parser and other components of IE.  In this case components in IE responsible for handling sited objects and possibly Silverlight itself have mutated the  `<object>` attributes.