# Creating Silverlight container with jQuery - does not work in IE9

Tags: jquery, silverlight, internet-explorer-9

I have a web application that uses jQuery to dynamically create an silverlight object.

This works well in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE9.

Here's a jsFiddle which demonstrates this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Bx9we/5/
In this example, the link to the .XAP file is fake, but your browsers should at least display the orange background. (In the actual application I'm working on the .XAP file is real and does display properly in Chrome and Firefox).

---

A possible red herring:

I'm looking at the generated HTML using the F12 developer tools. In firefox and chrome, it looks like this:

```
<object 
       data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
       type="application/x-silverlight-2" 
       id="SilverlightControl" height="292" width="396">
       <!-- continued --!>
```

But in IE9, it has transformed the data field into a different value.

```
   <object 
       id="SilverlightControl" 
       data="data:application/x-oleobject;base64,QfXq3+HzJEysrJnDBxUISgAJAADtKAAALR4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=" 
       width="396" 
       type="application/x-silverlight-2" 
       height="292">
          <!-- continued --!>
```

The transformation of the data tag is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240352/i-cant-read-silverlight-tag-in-ie).

---

Just in case jsFiddle isn't running:

The CSS

```
div.overlaid
{
    border:3px solid darkgray;
    background:black;
    height:312px;
    width:396px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}
.videoPopupCloseLink
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:6px;
    right:6px;
    color:White;
}
```

THE HTML

```
<button id="createOverlay">Create Overlay</button>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(function()
  {
      $('div.overlaid').remove();
      $('#createOverlay').click(function() {
            var div = $('<div />')
                .addClass('overlaid')
                .appendTo('body');

            var silverlightSource = './dummy_source.xap';
          var fileName='buy_duff_beer.wmv';
          var entityId=39874;
           var initParams = '<param id="initParams" name="initParams" value="fileName=' + fileName + ',entityid=' + entityId + '" />';
        $('<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" id="SilverlightControl" height="292" width="396" />')
                            .append($('<param></param>').attr({ name: "source", value: silverlightSource }))
                            .append("<param name='background' value='orange' />")
                            .append("<param name='onerror' value='onSilverlightError' />")
                            .append("<param name='minRuntimeVersion' value='4.0.50826.0' />")
                            .append("<param name='autoUpgrade' value='true' />")
                            .append(initParams)
                            .append('<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/></a>')
                            .appendTo(div);

         $('<a />')
                    .addClass('videoPopupCloseLink')
                    .text('close')
                    .click(function () { $('div.overlaid').remove() })
                    .appendTo(div);
}
    );
}
);
```

Comment: Just speculation - maybe IE is trying to load the SL application before the append() commands run? Can you try instantiating the whole thing at once to see if it works?

Comment: A publically accessible test page would be very useful to help discover the issue.

Comment: Would you not be better off having your Silverlight object in the original page (hidden) and simply move it to the appropriate div using JQuery where needed? Calls onto that object from JS are trivial (e.g. to tell it what to play).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're setting the Data attribute like that. That has the result of containing an object initialized withe a MIME type but no actual data. If you omit that attribute, is there a difference?

Comment: @Sander - OK, I've created a jsFiddle link that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @HiTech Magic - Thanks for the advice. I did exactly what you described and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it works, if you use correct html:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bx9we/7/

When creating an object tag in IE, you can not create it then add it to the dom
 in 2 operations. You have to create the object tag in an html string, then add the string to the dom.

$('some html').appendTo first creates the dom node - which won't work for object tag in IE.

```
$(function() {
$('div.overlaid').remove();

  $('#createOverlay').click(function() {

var silverlightSource = './dummy_source.xap';
var fileName='buy_duff_beer.wmv';
    var entityId=39874;

$("body").append('<div class="overlaid"><object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" id="SilverlightControl" height="292" width="396" >\
      <param name="source" value="'+silverlightSource+'"></param>\
      <param name="background" value="orange" ></param>\
      <param id="initParams" name="initParams" value="fileName=' + fileName + ',entityid=' + entityId + '" ></param>\
      </object></div>\
      ');

  });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Are you running IE in 64bit mode? 64bit is supported in SL5 but not in SL4.

Comment: I actually have a different page with a static Slverlight control, and IE9 is displaying that with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Would you not be better off having your Silverlight object in the original page (hidden) and simply move it to the appropriate div using JQuery where needed?  Calls onto that object from JS are trivial (e.g. to tell it what to play).

Comment: +1 because it was really useful and solved the problem I had. However, I'm going to hold off on the "Accept" button just in case somebody solves the underlying problem of creating Silverlight controls dynamically in IE9.